# Linear referencing with different "begin/end" offset

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, linear-referencing

Here is my problem: I have an axis passing in the middle of the street that would be used for linear referencing.

Now I need to draw each border of the road.

On the picture, I have no problem with the right part since the width of A and B is exactly the same, but is it possible to adapt the offset for the beginning and the end of the line to represent left side accordingly to the picture ?

[image: Road]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly to my knowledge. You can however create a table with mileage values (regular interval or at nodes where the offset changes). In the file you can specify two fields, e.g. 'offset_left' (make this one negative) and 'offset' right. You can then generate route events of these points with the offset taken from the offset fields (once right and once left). If you then connect the points, you have your boundaries.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I thought about this option, but I kinda lose "linear referencing" advantages since there is no more dynamism when a change occurs: I will need to launch a script to re-draw lines. I was hoping that ArcGIS had this option in its toolset :-)